# include_directories not working correctly

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to set up my library and project like in [this example](http://mirkokiefer.com/blog/2013/03/cmake-by-example/) using ExternalProject_Add.

I have a library like this:

```
lib
|-include
| |-a.hpp
|-src
| |-a.cpp
|-CMakeLists.txt
```

with the following CMakeLists.txt:

```py
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.0)
project(testlib)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRCS src/*.cpp; src/*.c)
add_library(TestLib STATIC ${SRCS})
install(TARGETS TestLib DESTINATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
```

My project looks like this:

```
app
|-src
| |-main.cpp
|-CMakeLists.txt
```

with the following CMakeLists.txt:

```py
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)
project(testapp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRCS src/*.cpp; src/*.c)
file(GLOB_RECURSE HDRS src/*.hpp; src/*.h)
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(
    TestLib
    PREFIX "contrib"
    DOWNLOAD_DIR "contrib"
    SOURCE_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/contrib/TestLib"
    URL "../../lib.zip"
)

add_library(monoengine STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET monoengine PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/contrib/TestLib/lib/libTestLib.a)
add_dependencies(monoengine TestLib)

add_executable(TestApp ${SRCS} ${HDRS})

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/contrib/TestLib/include/)
target_link_libraries(TestApp monoengine)
```

The library is getting installed correctly, I have the .a file in `contrib/TestLib/lib` and the .hpp file in `contrib/TestLib/include`

However in my main.cpp I cannot include a.hpp with `<TestLib/a.hpp>`, it only works with `"../contrib/TestLib/include/a.hpp"` or `<a.hpp>`.

How can I include it with `<TestLib/a.hpp>`?

Comment: You won't get `<TestLib/a.hpp>` to work without putting `a.hpp` directly in a directory `TestLib` somewhere.

Comment: @bames53: I just realized that. It was even written in the another answer I got to a previous question of mine. I feel dumb ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the include directory to the set of [`INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html#prop_tgt:INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES) of the imported target. This way, when adding a dependency with `target_link_libraries`, you automatically get the include directories for the dependency as well. Note that this feature requires CMake 2.8.12 or newer.

```
add_library(monoengine STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET monoengine PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION 
             ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/contrib/TestLib/lib/libTestLib.a)
set_property(TARGET monoengine PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
             ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/contrib/TestLib/include)
```

Note that for this to work, the dependency's source directory structure has to match the include directory structure (that is, you cannot `#include <TestLib/a.hpp>` if `a.hpp` is not located in a subdirectory `TestLib`). If this is an issue, you might need to add an install step to your `ExternalProject_Add` call and include from the install target directory instead of the source directory.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, it says `Imported target "monoengine" includes non-existent path "some path" in its INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.`. Maybe it's trying to access the path before it is created?

Comment: But I got it to work nonetheless with my previous approach. I had to put my headers into a subdirectory, as you were saying. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think there is currently a bug in CMake. See https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15052

Answer (score 2):

(follow up to @CosmicSansMS and @user1427799, sorry I'm not allowed to comment ...)

A work-around to the "Imported target includes non-existent path" is to manually create the folder using `file (MAKE_DIRECTORY)`, as suggested in the [bug report](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15052). The following works for me, with CMake 3.10.2:

```
set (__include "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/contrib/TestLib/include")

file (MAKE_DIRECTORY ${__include})
set_property (TARGET monoengine PROPERTY INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${__include})
```